# Historical Backlog Using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to develop a query that will show the historical backlog, month by month for applications my organization processes.

The table I'm querying has each row represent an application.

This is fairly simple for a single month by taking into account when the application was created and when it was closed. I can use the code below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM APPLICATIONS
WHERE TRUNC(CRTE_DTE,'mm') <= TO_DATE('09/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy')
AND (TRUNC(CLOS_DTE,'mm')> TO_DATE('09/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') OR CLOS_DTE IS
NULL)
;
```

What I would like to do, is create something like this but grouped by month.

i.e. with output that looks similar to:

- January 250
- February 350
- March 290

etc.

For my purposes, I'm defining backlog as any application that hadn't yet been closed by the time that month had ended while excluding any applications opened after that month had ended.

I don't have access to run PL/SQL, but if that's a requirement please let me know.

First time posting here, so if I didn't explain something correctly, let me know!

Comment: A good starting point is [mcve]; you could clarify your question by adding some sample data and desired result, explaining why you expect that output

Comment: You get the wrong answers if you use TRUNC() around dates the way you did. For example, create_date of 1 Sept 2016 at 3 pm will satisfy the condition if you truncate first. The conditions are exactly right if you DON'T use TRUNC. You just need to adjust the inequalities (strict or non-strict) to implement your business requirement as to how to treat create or close date that is exactly at midnight on 31 August (etc.) This will also make best use of an index on crte_dte and clos_dte, if you have indexes on them (as you should if performance is an issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT d.dt, COUNT(*)
FROM 
   APPLICATIONS a, 
   (SELECT ADD_MONTHS(:DATE1, ROWNUM-1) DT FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM<=MONTHS_BETWEEN(:DATE2, :DATE1)+1) d
WHERE TRUNC(a.CRTE_DTE,'mm') <= d.dt
  AND (TRUNC(a.CLOS_DTE,'mm')> d.dt OR CLOS_DTE IS NULL) 
GROUP BY D.DT
```

:date1 - start date, for example 08/01/2016, :date2 - end date, for example 10/01/2016, in subquery we get row for each month between :date1 and :date2, and then count backlog for them.